# Truncating all tables in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

Is there any way to truncate all tables in HSQLDB?

If this is not possible, is there any way to cascade delete tables with foreign key references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to truncate all the tables in a schema:

TRUNCATE SCHEMA  AND COMMIT

This command has some options that are described in the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_truncate_statement